# Comparação de conteúdo em matrizes

Tags: python, matriz, numpy

Tem alguma solução em python para utilizar algo semelhante o np.all em arrays que estão preenchidos com strings ou ints?

Abaixo um exemplo do que eu desejo, realizar a comparação de uma linha da matriz para verificar se todos os elementos são iguais.

```
tab2 = [
    ['X','O','X'],
    ['X','X','X'],
    ['O','O','O'],
]



for i in range(0, len(tab2)):        
    tab = tab2[:i]
    x = np.all(tab)
    print (x)
    if (x):
        break
    else: 
        tab = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizei a seguinte solução:

```
for i in range (0, len(tab)):
    if (tab[i].count('X') == len(tab)):
        print (i)
```

Basicamente esse código verifica se a quantidade de "X" no vetor é igual ao tamanho do vetor, o print é só um teste.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução é usar a função builtin `all` para verificar se todos os elementos da linha são iguais ao primeiro:

```py
tab2 = [
    ['X','O','X'],
    ['X','X','X'],
    ['O','O','O'],
]

def is_equal(row):
    return all([row[0]==row[i] for i in range(len(row))])

print([is_equal(r) for r in tab2])
```

Retorna:

```
[False, True, True]
```

Veja também a função `any`